# How to solve runSaga(options, saga, ...args): saga argument must be a Generator function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Main problem: I get following error
`runSaga(options, saga, ...args): saga argument must be a Generator function!` using type script

Description: I used snippet from course but it was in react, and I wanted it to put next lvl in typescript.

in store.ts

```
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
```

in root.ts

```
import { all } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { sliceOne } from "./sliceOnes";
import secondSlice from "./reducers/secondSlice";

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([... sliceOne,  secondSlice]);
}
```

Comment: Please show how you import that function

Comment: ``` import rootSaga from "./rootSaga";
 ```

Comment: Your error message indicates that it’s expecting a saga as the second parameter. It’s hard to tell exactly why you’re getting that error, or when.